# How can I set pageToken to get item lists from Google Cloud Storage via Java SDK?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I want to set pageToken to get items stored at Google Cloud Storage. I'm using Google API Client Library for Java v1.19.x.

I have no idea to generate pageToken from file path(or file name).

2 files stored in bucket.

- my-bucket

  - /test.csv
  - /test2.csv

When I tried [Google APIs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) with following parameters, I could get nextPageToken `Cgh0ZXN0LmNzdg==`.

And I found out that I can get `test.csv` string by decoding nextPageToken with base64.

- bucket: my-bucket
- pageToken:
- prefix: test
- maxResults: 1

`{"kind": "storage#objects", "nextPageToken": "Cgh0ZXN0LmNzdg==", ...}`

But How can I get `Cgh0ZXN0LmNzdg==` from `test.csv`?

Although I tried Base64 encoding, result didn't match.

```
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String lastFile = "test.csv"
String token = Base64.encodeBase64String(lastFile.getBytes());

String bucket = "my-bucket"
String prefix = "test"

Storage.Objects.List listObjects = client.objects().list(bucket);
listObjects.setPrefix(prefix);
listObjects.setPageToken(token);
long maxResults = 1;
listObjects.setMaxResults(maxResults);
do {
    Objects objects = listObjects.execute();
    List<StorageObject> items = objects.getItems();

    token = objects.getNextPageToken();
    listObjects.setPageToken(token);
} while (token != null);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the page token on the first request? You only have to set it on subsequent requests.

Comment: Thank you for comment.


My application saves last file name(download succeeded) at local config file.


And If something error occurs while downloading next file,
application try to get filelist again except files that download completed.

Comment: I don't think that will work. The page token is an opaque identifier. Resuming from a specific object is not supported.

Comment: As you say, page token seems opaque.

For your reference, I could get page token with following code when path length is shorter than 128byte.
Thank you.



    private String base64Encode(String path)
    {
        byte[] encoding;
        byte[] utf8 = path.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
        
        encoding = new byte[utf8.length + 2];
        encoding[0] = 0x0a;
        encoding[1] = new Byte(String.valueOf(path.length()));
        
        String s = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(encoding);
        return s;
    }

Comment: @sakama is it possible to post your answer and accept it, so others can benefit from it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get next token from file path string using following codes by myself.

**How to get nextToken from path string**

String nextToken = base64encode(0x0a + asciiCode + pathString)

asciiCode can be taken between 0x01(SOH) and 0x7f(DEL). It seems to depend on path length.

- my-bucket/

  - a/a(3byte) 0x03
  - a/ab(4byte) 0x04
  - test.txt(8byte) 0x08

**Notice**

If path length is longer than 1024 byte, another rule seems to apply. But I couldn't found out rules.

See also [Object Name Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-naming?hl=en)

```
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;

String lastFile = "test.csv"
String token = base64Encode(lastFile);

String bucket = "my-bucket"
String prefix = "test"

Storage.Objects.List listObjects = client.objects().list(bucket);
listObjects.setPrefix(prefix);
listObjects.setPageToken(token);
long maxResults = 1;
listObjects.setMaxResults(maxResults);
do {
    Objects objects = listObjects.execute();
    List<StorageObject> items = objects.getItems();

    token = objects.getNextPageToken();
    listObjects.setPageToken(token);
} while (token != null);

private String base64Encode(String path) {
    byte[] encoding;
    byte[] utf8 = path.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
    encoding = new byte[utf8.length + 2];
    encoding[0] = 0x0a;
    encoding[1] = new Byte(String.valueOf(path.length()));
    String s = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(encoding);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The page token is indeed encoded as `base64([LF] + length + name.bytes)` as answered by @sakama. In addition to his answer, the length of the array is a [varint](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#varints) which will answer how to encode names longer than 127 bytes. Example code:

```java
    private static String pageToken(String name) {
        var encodedName = name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        // Use initial size of +3 (0x0a + 2 bytes for length of max 1024)
        var bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(encodedName.length + 3);
        bos.write(0x0a);
        writeVarInt(bos, encodedName.length);
        bos.write(encodedName, 0, encodedName.length);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
    }

    public static void writeVarInt(ByteArrayOutputStream bos, int value) {
        while ((value & ~0x7f) != 0) {
            bos.write((value & 0x7f) | 0x80);
            value >>>= 7;
        }
        bos.write(value);
    }
```

[Maximum object name size](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects) is 1024

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is already answered and is applied to Java, I'd like to mention that this question applies to PHP as well.

With the help of the approved post from sakama above I figured out a PHP version of his solution.

The PHP equivalent for generating the token is as follow:
`base64_encode(pack('c', 0x0a) . pack('c', $path_string_length) . pack('a*', $path_string));`

The byte pattern seems indeed (as sakama already mentioned) to be:
`<line feed><line data length><line data>`

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I wanted! I was able to make my object scanner reentrant using this code.