# How can I set pageToken to get item lists from Google Cloud Storage via .Net

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-storage

The lifecycle I have.

User has a problem --> Set App in Debug --> App uploads local logs to our Server --> save logs in Google Cloud Storage.

Now I want to add this for the admin panel:

List all the logs, as links with their MediaLink attribute, for a specific user

Click on a specific link and Download the link

```
 public async Task<Page<Object>> ListObjectsWithDelimeter(string bucketName, string prefix, string delimiter)
    {
            //Uses prefix to emulate directories.
        var options = new ListObjectsOptions() { Delimiter = delimiter };

        var page = await _storageClient.ListObjectsAsync(
            bucketName, prefix, options).ReadPageAsync(100, CancellationToken.None);

        return page;

    }
```

Obviously we have a problem with this method.

1. Magic Number - 100
2. If there are more results, than the magic Number, they wont be displayed.

I checked google sample code , [HERE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-dotnet/blob/master/aspnet/3-binary-data/Models/DbBookStore.cs) and they base their pageSize on the size of their DB. However I dont know how many times a user would upload a log from their app, since its based on how many trips he/she takes. 
It can be 10, 100 or 1000.

How can I implement the next page token into my current listing method?

**Edit**: I found out that you should append the token like this, described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197294/how-to-change-to-next-page-on-google-storage-api), and I also saw that the JavaSDK has a parameter in the ListOptions SetNextPage Token, described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539589/how-can-i-set-pagetoken-to-get-item-lists-from-google-cloud-storage-via-java-sdk?rq=1). But I can find it in the .net API client? Is the client incomplete?